# Get the related model entries with a single GET request to the master model in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've one master model and six other models which are foreign key related to my master.

**My models:**

```
#MASTER TABLE
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4,editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

#RELATED TABLES
class EducationProfile(models.Model):
    degree_level = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    completion_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserDetails, related_name='education')

class AwardsRecognitions(models.Model):
    award_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    awarded_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    award_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserDetails, related_name='awards')
```

I'm trying to fetch the info of all the related models with me GET request to the `UserDetails` model. I've tried using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` in the `UserDetailsSerializer` but that is not giving me the expected output. The result is having only the related entry's id in the nested fields.

My Serializers:

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    education = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)
    awards = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only = True, many = True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        fields = '__all__'

class EducationProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = EducationProfile
        fields = '__all__'

class AwardsRecognitionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AwardsRecognitions
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Expected Result**:

> GET Request format - <<UserDetails_model_endpoint>>/<<user_id_primary_key>>/

> Response format -
>
> ```
> {"user_id" : <<user_id>>,
>  "first_name" : "foo",
>  "last_name" : "bar",
>  "education":[{"id":5,
>                "degree_level": "xxxx",
>                "degree":"xxxx",
>                "start_date":"xxxx",
>                "completion_date":"xxxx"},
>               {"id":7,
>                "degree_level": "yyyy",
>                "degree":"yyyy",
>                "start_date":"yyyy",
>                "completion_date":"yyyy"}],
>  "awards":[{"id":3,
>             "award_name":"nnnn",
>             "awarded_by":"nnnn",
>             "awarded_date":"nnnn"},
>            {"id":7,
>             "award_name":"mmm",
>             "awarded_by":"mmmm",
>             "award_date":"mmmm"}]
> ```

Kindly point me in the correct direction to achieve this, any idea is appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include serializers for the models you have created for related models instead of the primary key related field. PrimaryKeyRelatedField will give you only the primary key in the JSON as the name suggests.

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    education = EducationProfileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    awards = AwardsRecognitionsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        fields = '__all__'
```

For more details checkout https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this as well, I'm getting the expected output. Performance-wise I'm not sure if this is the best way to get the output. Can you kindly help me understand from that perspective?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by performance-wise? This is the recommended way of doing it mentioned in DRF docs. If by the performance you mean the number of queries generated because you are dealing with multiple related models then it will depend on your queryset, just make sure you don't run into N+1 query issue